# Input text into a text field using a button?

Tags: swift, button, textfield

I'm trying to make a VAT converter which gets the VAT percentage of a slider and applies it to a value taken from a UITextField, then outputs it to another text field. My button push action looks like this:

```
@IBaction func Calculate(sender: AnyObject){ 
var curentval = Int(Slider.value) // Get the vat % from the slider 
var sum = Sum.text.toInt() // 
var VAT = sum! * curentval/100 // this is what I'm trying to output in a text field that is called VAT
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this one

```
@IBOutlet weak var txtVat:UITextField!

@IBaction func Calculate(sender: AnyObject){ 
  var curentval = Int(Slider.value) // Get the vat % from the slider 
  var sum = Sum.text.toInt() 
  var finalVal = sum! * curentval/100
  txtVat.text = UInt8(finalVal)
}
```